# Add display property only from second item in for loop

Tags: php, css, for-loop

I am creating a simple image gallery that requires the **first image** to be shown first, while the images after are supposed to have a `display;none` property. How do I achieve it so that only the first image is different? The following is my code so far.

```
<div class="content">
    <?php 
    foreach($variants['productVariants'][0]['productVariantImages'] as $variantImage){
        if(isset($variantImage) && $variantImage['visible']){
    ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $variantImage['imagePath']; ?>" class="image_<?php echo $variantImage['id']; ?>" style="display:none" alt="" />
    <?php }}?>
</div>
```

My current output is

```
<div class="content">
    <img src="images/bigs/2.jpg" class="image_1" style="display:none" alt="">
     <img src="images/bigs/2.jpg" class="image_2" style="display:none" alt="">
     <img src="images/bigs/3.jpg" class="image_3" style="display:none" alt="">
</div>
```

I would like to be able to achieve the following

```
<div class="content">
     <img src="images/bigs/1.jpg" class="image_1" alt="">
     <img src="images/bigs/2.jpg" class="image_2" style="display:none" alt="">
     <img src="images/bigs/3.jpg" class="image_3" style="display:none" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: either use css or just use the `$key as $variantImage` with an `if` in the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple ways:

1. Using a variable (eg. `$first`, set it to `true` before the loop and to `false` at the end of the first iteration)
2. Using the keys of your (probably 0-indexed?) array (eg. `foreach($variants['productVariants'][0]['productVariantImages'] as $key => $variantImage){`, notice the `$key =>` part). You can then check if `$key` is 0 in the loop and that's your first element.
3. As @alirezasafian suggested, simply use CSS - this is probably the most versatile method.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use php for that, you can do it by css.

```
.content img:not(:first-child)
{
    display: none;
}
```

```css
.content img:not(:first-child) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <img src="images/bigs/1.jpg" class="image_1" alt="1">
  <img src="images/bigs/2.jpg" class="image_2" alt="2">
  <img src="images/bigs/3.jpg" class="image_3" alt="3">
</div>
```